# Form not submitting some variables after adding jquery inline datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im submitting a form thats submitting **firstname**, **lastname**, **email**, **date** to my database, but since ive made some changes only the **date** is being submitted.

It was all working fine until i decided to make the jquery datepicker show inline on the page rather than having to click on a field to show the datepicker.

To make this datepicker inline i changed some code to this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({altField: '#date'});
});
</script>


<form method="post" action="send.php">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="yourinfo" ><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Last Name" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Before i made the changes my code looked like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="send.php">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="yourinfo" ><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Last Name" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email Address" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
<input type="text" name ="date" id="datepicker" value="Enter Your Prediction" onFocus=this.value='' class="yourinfo"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

but this wasnt the way i wanted it to work as you had to click on the text field to display the datepicker.

is there anything that you can see that maybe preventing firstname lastname and email from being sent???

Comment: Have you tried to make the `#date` a text input instead of a hidden one?

Comment: i want the text field to be hidden though.  what happens is that when i select a date from the datepicker it has to placed in the field so the date variable can be sent but i dont want it visable.... i cant understand why what ive added is effecting the other fields though

Comment: check the value of your date is correct. check with your page source, echo your insert query and check whether all values are placing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be that you do not have double quotation marks around the values of `onFocus`. When I tripper them out, it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/william/eGGqS/1/

EDIT:

This one is closer to your example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/william/eGGqS/2/